# Product middle alignment with divs?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a variety of products on my online shop. Let's say I have three product pictures, that after resizing are:

```
100 x 20
100 x 100
100 x 180
```

100 x 180 is the max size that a window for products can take. In order to get perfect product placing, I need to get all three those images to fit into a window of 100 x 180. That is not very difficult:

```
<div class="products" style="height: 180px;">
 <div class="product1">
   <img src="prod1.jpg" />
 </div>
 <div class="product2">
   <img src="prod2.jpg" />
 </div>
 <div class="product3">
   <img src="prod3.jpg" />
 </div>
```

Now, the problem comes in that these images are all aligned at the top. I need them all to be MIDDLE aligned, like what tables would do. I could easily do this with tables, but I'm lost as to how to do it with CSS. Is it as simple as CSS or is there a nifty JQuery plugin for something like this?

Comment: You'll probably need to calculate all products `outerHeight` and `outerWidth` and then position at 50% top and 50% left relative to container `products` and `margin-left: -outerHeight/2` and `margin-right: -outerWidth/2`...Usual stuff for centering things. See this simple example http://jsfiddle.net/elclanrs/RMsSh/

Answer (score 0):

`.products div { line-height: 180px; }`

…though you should ideally be using a list of some sort instead of just divs.